# Understand the signature of partially applied function for function literal

Tags: scala

I'm having trouble understand the signature of partially applied function for function literal. For example, consider the following function and method definitions that work the same way:

```
def meth(x: Int): Unit = ()
val func = (x: Int) => ()
```

Now create a partially applied function out of each of the method/function above. Notice the signatures of the resulting function:

```
val f = meth _  // Int => Unit
val g = func _  // () => Int => Unit
```

I don't understand why the signature of `func _` includes a `() =>` part, which makes `g` must be called like `g()(1)` rather than `g(1)`.

Comment: You can treat this as a bug. In scala 2.13 you will get error message `_ must follow method` for `val g = func _`, as eta extension used for transforming method to function literals should work only for methods.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko Do you have a reference to this bug or proposed change?

Comment: my fault. Not a bug. Works in scala 2.13 as well on top level methods. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525520/scala-eta-expansion-of-function-values-not-methods -  one more answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, consider the following function and method definitions that work the same way:

Methods and functions are *not* the same in Scala. They're in fact very different. Methods are not first-class objects, whereas functions are. That is, you'll never have a variable whose type is a method type.

As a consequence of this, let's look at the types *without* the underscores.

```
val f = meth
val g = func
```

Since `meth` is a method, it's going to be *called*. So the first line will try to call `meth()` with no arguments, an error. `func`, however, is an ordinary value, so there's no trouble. We'll just have another alias to `func` called `g`.

```
val f = meth _
val g = func _
```

In order to allow us to treat methods as objects, Scala introduces the `_` syntax. When used with a method, it converts that method into a function object. So `meth _` is a special method syntax which turns it into a function. On the other hand, `func _` is taking a *value* (remember, functions are objects, just like strings or anything else) and lifting it to be a function object. The "easiest" way to do that is to add an empty argument list, so that's exactly what Scala does.

tl;dr Putting `_` after a name turns the thing into a function object. If the thing is a method, it doesn't apply it. If the thing is a value (including but not limited to a function), it produces a new function object.

Comment: "If the thing is a value (including but not limited to a function), it produces a new function object." summarizes it pretty good. Just realized I can `val x = 1; val f = x _; f() == 1`.